# Filling out a choice field in Django using other models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to make a choice field in a form that adds a choice every time I make a new instance in another model. Here is the relevant code:

models.py

```
class Instructor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Schedules(models.Model):
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

forms.py

```
class ScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    instructor = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

I want it so that each choice in the instructor choice field of the schedule form will always be first_name + ' ' + last_name and will add more choices each time a new Instructor instance is made. I heard that using ModelChoiceField is a good idea, but I only want part of the instances, not all of it. Do I need to use population or sqlite3 operations? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField) with normal django form to achieve it. Since you want to customize the option string, you need to subclass ModelChoiceField.

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
from yourapp.models import Instructor


class InstructorChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    """Retun first_name + last_name as option string """

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "{0} {1}".format(obj.first_name,obj.last_name)


class ScheduleForm(forms.Form):
    instructor = InstructorChoiceField(queryset = Instructor.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am right, you want to populate your instructor field on ScheduleForm from the Instructor model.
what you can do is add a ForeignKey to your Schedules model reference to Instructor model, and then you can populate your form using Schedules Model.

**models.py**

```
class Instructor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" %(self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Schedules(models.Model):
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor)
```

and now you can [create your form using model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/)

**form.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Schedules

#Create the form class.
class ScheduleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedules
```